# Cómo calcular los días entre un rango de fechas, cuando CADA DIA tiene un peso o significancia? (NO es DATEDIFF)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-management

> Hola a todos !
>
> Trato de calcular los días que un vendedor ha dejado de trabajar
> (Ausencias), en un rango de fechas, pero no con la diferencia
> matemática (DATEDIFF), sino con la determinada por la empresa...
>
> Contexto...
>
> Sabemos que para calcular los días que hay entre un rango de fechas,
> debemos utilizar DATEDIFF, y su resultado será un INT... Hasta allí,
> normal.
>
> Pero qué si te digo, que en la empresa donde trabajo, los días pesan (o significan)
> distinto, es decir,
>
> Días hábiles = 1,  Sábados = 0.5,  Domingos y Festivos = 0
>
> Por ejemplo, entre *Viernes* **05/03/2021** y el *Lunes*
> **08/03/2021**, hay **2.5** días (Viernes05 (**1**) + Sábado06 (**0.5**) + Domingo07 (**0**) + Lunes08 (**1**) )
>
> Usando el DATEDIFF simplemente dirá que son 4.

```
select 
SUM(n_dia_habil) Dias_Ausente
from
[Dimension Tiempos]
where DATE_KEY between '2021-03-05' and '2021-03-08'
```

> Cuyo resultado es 2.5

[image: Salida QRY Dimension Tiempos]

> Con el fin de tener la data organizada, tengo una tabla de "*Dimensión
> de tiempos*", con el peso de cada día...
>
> Por otro lado, tengo la tabla Ausencias, donde se almacenan los datos
> de los colaboradores que han estado ausentes por diversas
> circunstancias, con el mencionado rango de fechas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Cómo podría agregarle a las Ausencias el cálculo de los días que para
> la empresa, cada colaborador estuvo ausente.???
>
> Les agradezco un montón.

Comment: Bienvenido Diego Martinez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: ¿Tienes una tabla de fechas tal que puedas listar día por día cada fecha? si la tuvieras es cosa de ver que tipo de día es cada uno y sumar el coeficiente que le corresponde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que Dimension Tiempos actuara como un catalogo de dias donde se encuentran siempre todas las fechas, podrias hacer un select a Ausencias y utilizar CROSS APPLY
para seleccionar los Dimension Tiempos que se encuentren entre la fecha_inicio y fecha_fin de Ausencias, esto lo que haria seria replicar cada registro por cada coincidencia, y ya con eso sumas N_DIA_HABIL.

```
SELECT A.nombre, SUM(DT.N_DIA_HABIL) as total from Ausencias AS A
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT * FROM Dimension_Tiempos as DT 
    WHERE DT.date_key >= A.fecha_inicio AND DT.date_key <= A.fecha_fin
) as DT
GROUP BY A.nombre
```

En este caso agrupo por el nombre de la persona que se encuentra en ausencia, para solo sumar los de esa persona, tambien podrias agruparlo por el id de la Ausencias(en caso que lo tengas) para saber el dato por cada registro de Ausencias

Comment: Muchas Gracias !! Efectivamente, el cross apply fue el que me sirvió !!